# Session data lost automatically without click logout in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables

I have a web application using codeigniter with users about 200. If about 100 users login to the system at the same time, sometimes the user logout automatically or redirect to the login page without click logout before.

My Code.

Login Helper (Load in Construst to check login or not)

```
function is_logged_in()
{
    //Get Codeigniter Instance
    $obj =& get_instance();

    $is_logged_in = $obj->session->userdata('LOGGED_IN');

    if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
    {   
        $obj->session->set_flashdata('message','<div class="error_login"><b>ERROR:</b> Silahkan login terlebih dahulu.</div>');

        //If no session, redirect to login page
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }

 }
```

Controller.

```
public function verify()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    //Query the database
    $row = $this->Loginmodel->verify($username,$password);

    if (count($row)) {

        $dataSession = array(
            'userid' => $row->userid,
            'role' => $row->role,
            'prov_cd' => $row->prov_cd,
            'kab_cd' => $row->kab_cd,
            'LOGGED_IN'=> true,
            'MODAL'=> true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($dataSession);

        redirect('dashboard','refresh');

    } 
    else
    {
         $this->session->set_flashdata('message','<div class="error_login"><b>ERROR:</b> Username atau password salah.</div>');
         redirect('login','refresh');
    }

}
```

I think it's because I store many parameters in session data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your count($row) can you please specify it to be

```
COUNT($row) == 1
```

So I sorta understand what you are trying to do, if the $row returns a count of 0 then the user name password didn't verify, if it returns a single user example

```
== 1
```

then the user name is correct and did verify. Try this solution.

as per php documentation it does not return a Boolean true or false. Try that please. And also what errors are you getting?

Also for further implementation and I quote "Counts all elements in an array, or something in an object." so just calling

```
COUNT($row) { // If it is true or not will not work
```

I suspect you have to explicitly state if the count is == 1 then yes we did get a return on the query let the person proceed.

Alright I will also expand on this topic a bit more but from a CI standpoint!

I suspect that you are not checking if you session is set either... and what I recommend is to create a MY_Controller situation. It is very easy and will reduce trouble for for...

take a look at this code please :

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller { // Create your custom controller
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Then in the same file do the following :

class MY_logincontroller extends MY_Controller { // Extend the class you created above

```
public function __construct() { 
    parent::__construct();
    $this -> load -> model('login_model'); // Load your login model
    $loggedin = $this -> session -> userdata('loggedin'); // set your user information
    $username = $this -> session -> userdata('username'); // Set your user information

    if ((!isset($loggedin)) || ($loggedin != TRUE)) { // This will check if the the session variable is set or if it is equal to logged in, if not it will send to a access denied page
        $this -> session -> unset_userdata('loggedin'); // If access denied happens unset user data logged in (just to be sure) and destroy all other session stuff
        $this -> session -> sess_destroy();
        $this -> load -> view('messages/accessdenied_view');
        $this -> output -> _display();
        die();
    }
    $this -> output -> set_header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');
    $this -> output -> set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    $this -> output -> set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
    $this -> output -> set_header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
}
```

Hopefully this clears some stuff up for you

Comment: OK, i've tried it. Thanks. But, does it the reason that cause the session data lost automatically ? thanks.

Comment: I suspect that your your if statement is failing period. Since you are checking if COUNT($row) is TRUE. Take a look into your config file check on the expiration. You session data (once you implement a proper authentication system) should not be destroyed assuming that you the coder are not mistakenly destroying it.

Comment: I think your not checking if the session is there or not, I updated my answer. Also the code I posted should be put application/core

Comment: $this -> session -> unset_userdata('loggedin'); // If access denied happens unset user data logged in (just to be sure) and destroy all other session stuff
        $this -> session -> sess_destroy();
        $this -> load -> view('messages/accessdenied_view');
        $this -> output -> _display();
        die(); I dont't understand about that split codes ? Why should I use that? thanks.

Comment: Well first, I always manually unset session data that I set. Then I call the session destroy to do the rest for me. In codeigniter if you just put die() and then the Access Denied you will get a white screen because it kills or "die()'s" the script. So once you do the redirect then you have to display the redirect before you call the die() function. It is just to be sure.